# PyQGIS and Time Manager Plugin

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, timemanager

Where can I find more information regarding using the Python interface in QGIS with the Time Manager plugin. I made an animation in QGIS and am trying to automate some processes with Python, however I cannot find much info on the internet.

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using? QGIS 3.14 has a native time manager now with a proper API for PyQGIS.

Comment: I am using 3.14, are you referring to the "temporal controller" feature

Comment: Yes, so why are you using the Time Manager plugin? https://anitagraser.com/2020/05/10/timemanager-is-dead-long-live-the-temporal-controller/

Comment: I have tried to use it, but it only accepts timestamps in the form Day-Month-Year Hour:Minute:Second however my timestamp data is in the form Hour:Minute:Second so it is not compatible

Comment: It should be compatible. Where is the layer stored? In DB? File? Did you configure the form with the correct date time format? Where are you blocked with the new feature?

Comment: The layer is stored in a db table, with a column called "timescale" that has entries in the format hours:minutes:seconds. I am having trouble figuring out what to put for the start and end expressions in the "Start and End Date/Time From Expressions" configuration in the temporal properties of the layer.

Comment: Also, when I try to choose the "Single field with date/time" config. the "field" drop down menu is unresponsive and does not let me choose anything.

Comment: Is your field a Date or DateTime field? If not, you can make a virtual one, using the expression `to_date`, or do it on the DB side.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I mentioned that the field only has time, and no date. For example a possible timestamp would be 12:01:12